# I am looking for a way to copy cell formulas based on criteria to specific worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA coding and have no prior coding experience. I have been primarily taking code I have found and making modifications to it to fit my needs.

I am currently using this bit of VBA to identify what rows need to be copied from a "master list" and copy them to the specified worksheet:

```
Sub MovePerson()
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Sheet1.Activate

Dim RNG As Range

Set RNG = Range([C1], Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

On Error Resume Next

   With RNG
.AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:="Name"
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Persons Name").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

Essentially what I have is a worksheet that multiple people make entries into. I am using this to grab people's specific entries and export them to worksheets for analysis. I have an "update" button that I press that runs this piece of VBA for each person that makes entries into the "Sheet1" worksheet.

My issue is that I need the MovePerson sub to copy cell formulas and not just the text in the cell. I have tried using different VBA copy functions but that created an issue with copying the same entry multiple times each time I would hit my "update" button.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you separated the copy and paste? Then you could use `Range.PasteSpecial`:

```
With RNG
    .AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:="Name"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Persons Name").Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormulas)
    .AutoFilter
End With
```